# How to group a column(Travel Fare) in ranges (0-100),(100-200) like wise

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Table where there are Bookings records kept. I have to group the no. of bookings based on Fare ranges (0-100),(100-200) like wise. Fares are up to 3 decimal points. Please help

Comment: total_fare
900.00
4543.80
2400.00
1231.90
1050.00
131.50
350.00
414.95
800.00
719.95
719.95

Comment: Can you provide table definition, sample data and what you expect the final output to look like

Comment: Its a booking table, where fare for every booking is recorded. The fare is up to 2 decimal points. I want to club the fare ranges. Like how many bookings in 0-100 rs fare bracket, 101 to 200rs fare bracket and so on. I am very new to SQL and to Stack over flow. I do not really know table definition and dont know how to share a sample data set.

Comment: Have a read of this.  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I will surely go through this. But for now can you please share your email address so that I can share the data sample and show you my existing query. I have to turn it around today itself

Answer (score 0):

Does something like work for you?

Making some assumptions and a rudimentary table definition

```
DECLARE @Booking TABLE(
     Id         INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,TravelFare DECIMAL(10,3)
)
INSERT INTO @Booking
        ( TravelFare )
VALUES
        ( 5 ),( 17 ),( 43 ),( 115 ),( 135 ),( 167 ),( 221 ),( 278 ),( 325 ),( 354 ),( 387 )


SELECT
     COUNT(X.TravelFare)    'Count'
    ,X.TravelFareGroup
FROM
(
SELECT
     TravelFare
    ,CASE
        WHEN TravelFare BETWEEN 0 AND 100 THEN '0-100'
        WHEN TravelFare BETWEEN 101 AND 200 THEN '101-200'
        WHEN TravelFare BETWEEN 201 AND 300 THEN '201-300'
        WHEN TravelFare BETWEEN 301 AND 400 THEN '301-400'
     END 'TravelFareGroup'
FROM
    @Booking
) X
GROUP BY
    TravelFareGroup
```